# How to remove the background colour of HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a web app for a side project and not sure how to remove the grey background-colours behind each of the images. To test the back-end, I have implemented my HTML page with CSS and JavaScript. I'm not sure certain whether I need to change it from CSS or JavaScript code..

[image]

I tried everything by making the background-colour as white or transparent, but it doesn't seem to work properly.

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Good Cop, Bad Cop</title>
  <style>
    .view-image img {
      margin-left: 90px;
    }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/landing.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/coach_selection.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/4.6.1/firebase-ui-auth.css" />

</head>

<body>
  
  <div class="image">
    <div>
      <button type="button" id="dog-button" class="btn btn-light">
        <img src="../images/dog.png" id="dog" alt="dog">
      </button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="button" id="mother-button" class="btn btn-light">
        <img src="../images/mother.png" id="mother" alt="mother">
      </button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="button" id="soldier-button" class="btn btn-light">
        <img src="../images/military.png" id="soldier" alt="soldier">
      </button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="button" id="teacher-button" class="btn btn-light">
        <img src="../images/teacher.png" id="teacher" alt="teacher">
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="view-image" style="display:none;">
      <img src="" width="150" height="150" />
      <div class="button" id="button-other"><span>Other</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="button" id="button-confirm" onclick="redirectHome()">
    <span>Confirm</span>
  </div>
  
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.10/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.10/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.10/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/4.6.1/firebase-ui-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="../scripts/FireBase_API.js"></script>
    <script src="../scripts/coach_scripts/coach_selection.js"></script>
    
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
.image {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.image img {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.image img:hover {
  border: solid 2px #1e88e5;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.image #mother img:hover {
  border: solid 2px #1e88e5;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.image img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 30%;
}

.button{
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 10px auto 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  background-color: rgb(43, 43, 219);  
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.button:hover{
   background-color: #242424;
}
.button:active{
   background-color: #121212;
}

.button > span{
  color: #eeeeee;
  text-align: center;
}
```

JavaScript

```
var elementSelected = null;
var typeSelected = false;

$(document).on('click', '.image > img', function(){
  $('.image > img').each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  })
  $(this).addClass('active');
  elementSelected = $(this);
  typeSelected = false;
});

$(document).on('input', '#text-src', function(){
  $('.image > img').each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  })
  elementSelected = $(this);
  typeSelected = true;
})

$(document).on('click', '#button-confirm', function(){
  $('.image').hide();
  if(typeSelected == true){
    $('.view-image > img').attr('src', elementSelected.val());
    $('.button').hide();
  }
  else{
    $('.view-image > img').attr('src', elementSelected.attr('src'));
  }
  $('.view-image').fadeIn('high');
})

$(document).on('click', '#button-other', function(){
  $('.view-image').hide();
  $('.image').fadeIn('high');
})
```

Comment: Thanks for including your code-- would it be possible to distill this down into a [mcve] in a snippet in the question body?  Otherwise, testing this out will likely require each individual visitor to this page to do that in their own answer, which is a high barrier to entry that might deter would be answerers from assisting...

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I deleted all the unnecessary codes in the HTML. I wasn't sure what to delete in CSS and JS so remained as it is.

Comment: To solve this kind of issue, you should use your browser DevTools like Chrome DevTools : https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/ Just inspect your button and you'll see the ` background-color`property`.

Comment: Probably coming from bootstrap. You can override the background color in `.btn` and/or `.btn-light` classes if need be.

Comment: Hey this actually worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The light grey is provided by the class `btn-light` on the respective button elements. This class is defined in bootstrap.min.css. If you remove it, the buttons are styled as default, without background color.

Answer (score -1):

it is from your css for the button element.

```
.button{
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 10px auto 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  background-color: rgb(43, 43, 219);  
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

just remove the background-color.

I think you want to have hover effect on your round image. you just need to add the radius to the image and button elements.

Comment: I don't think that's right. The `.button` css is for an element with a class named `button`. Not a button element. Only the "Confirm" and "Other" buttons have that class.

Comment: Yea this just removes the button